# 502 bad gateway on customising wordpress search to include ACF custom taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, search

My requirement is that I have to modify wordpress custom search to include custom taxonomies.

You can find below Code that I am using for same in my `functions.php`.

But when I am trying to execute this code on my staging environment 
URL is http://panolam.staging.wpengine.com/?s=metal

I am getting 502 Bad Gateway nginx error. When I checked error logs on wpengine what I found this:

> PHP Warning: mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in /nas/content/staging/panolam/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1931

It shows that some query taking so much time or anything else it can be.

I looked for solution for this on google and found that to change the max_allowed_packet to 16M instead of 1M in the my.ini MySQL settings, but I dont want to do this. Can anybody tell what I can improve in my code to prevent this issue?

```
add_filter('posts_join', 'websmart_search_join' );
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'websmart_search_groupby' );
add_filter('posts_where', 'websmart_search_where' );

function websmart_search_join( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( is_search() && !is_admin()) {
            $join .= "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS m ON ($wpdb->posts.ID      = m.post_id) ";
    }
    return $join;
}

function websmart_search_groupby( $groupby ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( is_search() && !is_admin()) {
            $groupby = "$wpdb->posts.ID";
    }
    return $groupby;
}

function websmart_search_where( $where ) {
    global $wpdb, $wp_query;
    if( is_search() && !is_admin()) {
            $where = "";
            $search_terms = se_get_search_terms();
            $n = !empty($wp_query->query_vars['exact']) ? '' : '%';
            $searchand = '';
            if (count($search_terms) < 1) {
                    // no search term provided: so return no results
                    $search = "1=0";
            } else {
                    foreach( $search_terms as $term ) {
                            //$term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
                            $term = $wpdb->esc_like( $term );

                            // Get term by name in Custom taxonomy.
                            $term_details = get_term_by('name', $term, 'pattern_type');
                            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($term_details) ; die();
                            $search .= "{$searchand}(($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR (m.meta_value LIKE '{$n}{$term_details->term_id}{$n}'))";
                            $searchand = ' AND ';
                    }
            }
            $where .= " AND ${search} ";
            $where .= " AND (m.meta_key IN ('pattern_type')) ";
            $where .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_type IN ( 'post', 'page', 'product')) ";
            $where .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish') ";
    }
    return $where;
}


// Code from Search Everywhere plugin
function se_get_search_terms()
{
    global $wpdb, $wp_query;
    $s = isset($wp_query->query_vars['s']) ? $wp_query->query_vars['s'] : '';
    $sentence = isset($wp_query->query_vars['sentence']) ? $wp_query->query_vars['sentence'] : false;
    $search_terms = array();

    if ( !empty($s) )
    {
            // added slashes screw with quote grouping when done early, so done later
            $s = stripslashes($s);
            if ($sentence)
            {
                    $search_terms = array($s);
            } else {
                    preg_match_all('/".*?("|$)|((?<=[\\s",+])|^)[^\\s",+]+/', $s, $matches);
                    $search_terms = array_map(create_function('$a', 'return trim($a, "\\"\'\\n\\r ");'), $matches[0]);
            }
    }
    return $search_terms;
}
```

Comment: This seems like to much work, to just add taxonomies to search?

Comment: this answer looks much cleaner and easier? : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228645/how-to-add-custom-taxonomy-to-search

Comment: Actually this code worked very well on my local wamp server but I am facing problem on staging server. @Stender let me try code on this link, if it works for me.

Comment: sorry @Stender this is not working as per my requirement.

Comment: Can anyone help me with my present code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done few of changes to my code , though it seems lot of code but its working fine as per my requirement.

```
add_filter('posts_join', 'websmart_search_join' );
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'websmart_search_groupby' );
add_filter('posts_where', 'websmart_search_where' );

function websmart_search_join( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( is_search() && !is_admin()) {
            $join .= "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS m ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = m.post_id) ";
            $join .= "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = tr.object_id)  ";
            $join .= "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON (tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id) ";
            $join .= "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms AS t ON (t.term_id = tt.term_id) ";
    }
    return $join;
}

function websmart_search_groupby( $groupby ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( is_search() && !is_admin()) {
            $groupby = "$wpdb->posts.ID";
    }
    return $groupby;
}

function websmart_search_where( $where ) {
    global $wpdb, $wp_query;
    if( is_search() && !is_admin()) {
            $where = "";
            $search_terms = se_get_search_terms();
            $n = !empty($wp_query->query_vars['exact']) ? '' : '%';
            $searchand = '';
            if (count($search_terms) < 1) {
                    // no search term provided: so return no results
                    $search = "1=0";
            } else {
                    foreach( $search_terms as $term ) {
                            //$term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
                            $term = $wpdb->esc_like( $term );

                            // Get term by name in Custom taxonomy.
                            $term_details = get_term_by('name', $term, 'pattern_type');
                            $search .= "{$searchand}(($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR (m.meta_value LIKE '{$n}{$term_details->term_id}{$n}'))";
                            $searchand = ' AND ';
                    }
            }
            $where .= " AND {$search} ";
            $where .= " AND (m.meta_key IN ('pattern_type')) ";
            $where .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_type IN ( 'post', 'page', 'portfolio_page', 'product', 'cptbc', 'technical_doc', 'whats_new')) ";
            $where .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish') ";
    }
    return $where;
}


// Code from Search Everywhere plugin
function se_get_search_terms()
{
    global $wpdb, $wp_query;
    $s = isset($wp_query->query_vars['s']) ? $wp_query->query_vars['s'] : '';
    $sentence = isset($wp_query->query_vars['sentence']) ? $wp_query->query_vars['sentence'] : false;
    $search_terms = array();

    if ( !empty($s) )
    {
            // added slashes screw with quote grouping when done early, so done later
            $s = stripslashes($s);
            if ($sentence)
            {
                    $search_terms = array($s);
            } else {
                    preg_match_all('/".*?("|$)|((?<=[\\s",+])|^)[^\\s",+]+/', $s, $matches);
                    $search_terms = array_map(create_function('$a', 'return trim($a, "\\"\'\\n\\r ");'), $matches[0]);
            }
    }
    return $search_terms;
}
```